# Why Math.pow evaluating to a wrong value for long data type in java

Tags: java, long-integer

I am trying to solve a mathematical problem in geeksforgeeks wherein I have to calculate the 15 raised to the power 15.

```
long result = (long)Math.pow(a, b);
```

Here `a,b = 15` 
Why  the above expression evaluates to `437893890380859392` when it should be `437893890380859375`

Comment: Because floating point.  Math.pow returns a `double`.

Comment: Take a look at the range of the data type returned by Math.pow and see if it can hold the result you expect. I use wolframalpha.com for a convenient tool for large calculations that might exceed the capacity of Java

Comment: Why are you casting it to `long`? Math.pow returns a `double`.

Comment: Your type cast comes too late! Math.pow has already completed and overflowed.

Comment: Floating point is an approximation: a finite sum of powers of 2. Huge doubles will increase by more than 1 between adjacent double values.

Comment: @nicomp: That doesn't look like an overflow to me.  All of the digits are the same except the last two.  It's simply a small loss of precision.

Answer (score 3):

Better use `BigInteger`, it can handle even bigger values :

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("15").pow(15);    
System.out.println(bigInteger);
```

Comment: new BigDecimal(15).pow(15) can be used also